# assigning variable twice or not?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
name = '' 
while name != 'your name':
      print('please type your name.')
      name = input()
print('Thank you!')
```

Question: this is part of a coding example excercise. the program runs correctly. But my question is, aren't we assigning the variable-name twice here, 1st- as empty string, 2nd-as input(), and if so, assigning a variable twice is still okay ?

Comment: Sure, `for i in range(50)` will assign variable `i` 50 times. And by the way, use `name = input('please type your name: ')`

Comment: It's totally ok to reuse variables – just be sure that it's not confusing for you to use in the future. In your case, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is okay to define the variable twice, since you need it for the loop. Another way to do this would be to allow the loop to continue forever, until you explicitly break out of it. For example, you could rewrite your example as:

```
while True:
    name = input('please type your name')
    if name:
        break
print name
```

In this case, instead of pre-defining name, you create a loop that will start and continue until you issue a `break` statement (since the loop condition is `True`).
After getting the name using `input`, the conditional `if name` will allow you to break out of the loop, as long as a name was entered.

As @eli_dink points out, the following is probably better practice:

```
waiting_for_name = True
while waiting_for_name:
    name = input('please type your name')
    if name:
        waiting_for_name = False
print name
```

Comment: I do this all the time, but in general you should avoid `while True:`

Set a variable to `False` and have it change to `True` when you want to break out. Then you can do `while some_var:`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a variable name as many times as you need to. Each time you do, that name is unbound from the object it used to refer to, and rebound to the result of the RHS of the assignment.

This is quite common inside loops, where you might do a similar series of calculations at each iteration - it's also implicitly used in a standard Python `for` loop - for example:

```
for letter in "mystring":
    print(letter)
```

You can see that the name `letter` refers to a different object each time around the loop. That loop is in fact an easier to read version of this loop:

```
mystring = "mystring"
i = 0
while i < len(mystring):
    letter = mystring[i]
    print(letter)
    i = i + 1
```

To make the `while` loop work, we had to add the variable `i`, whose value changes constantly throughout the loop (which is normally hidden in the behind-the-scenes mechanics of the `for` loop). We also rebind the name `letter` each time around the loop, which is just what the `for` loop does. This type of pattern would be quite difficult, if not impossible, if we weren't allowed to reuse the variable names in this way.

Note that this isn't something specific to loops: it just happens to be very commonly used there. You might also see it, for example, if you have a long calculation which doesn't fit nicely in one line - it can be useful to 'build it up' over several lines, reusing the same variable each time (although sometimes it *is* better style to find different meaningful names for the intermediate values, particularly if there are other things going on in between).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's ok. That's why it's called "variable". [It literally means "able to vary"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/variable#English).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @200OK Huh? That's exactly what I did. It's all there. Did you only click my sentence but not read it? And the link is provided for reference. I only made it a link is to show that I'm not making it up and to provide a convenient reference if someone wonders. I think that's **good** style.

Comment: @200OK And I know from my own experience that I sometimes rote-learn a technical term without thinking much about it and only later have a great aha! moment where I realize that I can actually deconstruct the word and understand why something is called what it's called. "Variable" might actually have been such a word for me. And none of the other answers had pointed it out, so I did. Pretty disappointing that such help is apparently discouraged here (judging by the downvote).

Comment: Cool dude. I just reviewed your answer. I did't discouraged you.My comment is clear and simple that your link might be an answer but it is better to include some content with the link.Cheers  :)

Comment: @200OK Hmm, not clear whether you see your mistake now. It can't be better to include some content when I **did** do exactly that. Quite possibly I even copied&pasted it.